# How to add a gripper to a PropertySheet?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a class derived from `CPropertySheet`, and i want to insert a "gripper" on the bottom right of the dialog.
my dialog already is resizable, i just can't insert the gripper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any special APIs to do that. One option is to draw it manually, then override `ON_WM_NCHITTEST` and return `HTBOTTOMRIGHT` for gripper's position. For example:

```
void CMyDialog::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect();
    rc.left = rc.right - ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL);
    rc.top = rc.bottom - ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);
    HTHEME ht = OpenThemeData(m_hWnd, L"STATUS");
    if (ht)
    {
        DrawThemeBackground(ht, dc, SP_GRIPPER, 0, &rc, 0);
        CloseThemeData(ht);
    }
    else
    {
        dc.DrawFrameControl(rc, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLSIZEGRIP);
    }
}

LRESULT CMyDialog::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
{
    CRect rc;
    GetWindowRect(rc);
    rc.left = rc.right - ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL);
    rc.top = rc.bottom - ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);
    if (rc.PtInRect(point))
        return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
    return CDialog::OnNcHitTest(point);
} 

void CMyDialog::OnSize(UINT type, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialog::OnSize(type, cx, cy);
    Invalidate(TRUE);
}
```

Add to message map:

```
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_NCHITTEST()
ON_WM_SIZE()
```

Comment: Thanks its working. but i commented the first if (Linker problems). Why do i need the first if?

Comment: Yes you can remove `OpenThemeData` and other theme functions if you don't want it. The two methods draw the gripper image slightly differently. `DrawThemeBackground` draws it the same way as Notepad's gripper, as seen when Visual Style is enabled.

Comment: I like to use `m_bmpResize.LoadOEMBitmap(OBM_SIZE);` and then assign it to a `CStatic` but I can't get the rendering correct when resizing.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle `DrawThemeBackground` draws a themed gripper, like in OpenSaveDialog. Comment that out and use `DrawFrameControl` if you want the old look.

Comment: I will look tomorrow. Start new question if needed.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965899/adding-a-resize-anchor-to-derived-cmfcpropertysheet-class

Comment: I also tried your exact code and I still get rendering issues.