# MFC: Scrollbar gripper has a flashing cursor?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am using the following code to draw a scrollbar gripper for resizing window.

```
    // create a gripper in the bottom-right corner
    if (m_bShowGripper && ((GetStyle() & WS_THICKFRAME) != 0))
    {
        SMovingChild s;
        s.m_rcInitial.SetRect(-GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL), -GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYHSCROLL), 0, 0);
        s.m_rcInitial.OffsetRect(rcClient.BottomRight());
        m_hGripper = CreateWindow(_T("Scrollbar"), _T("size"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_SIZEGRIP,
                                  s.m_rcInitial.left, s.m_rcInitial.top, s.m_rcInitial.Width(), s.m_rcInitial.Height(),
                                  this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), NULL);
        ASSERT(m_hGripper != NULL);
        if (m_hGripper != NULL)
        {
            s.m_hWnd = m_hGripper;
            s.m_dXMoveFrac = 1.0;
            s.m_dYMoveFrac = 1.0;
            s.m_dXSizeFrac = 0.0;
            s.m_dYSizeFrac = 0.0;
            m_MovingChildren.push_back(s);

            // put the gripper first in the z-order so it paints first and doesn't obscure other controls
            ::SetWindowPos(m_hGripper, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    }
```

Originally from here: [How to create a resizable CDialog in MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138040/how-to-create-a-resizable-cdialog-in-mfc). The code runs OK, but the gripper has a flashing block like cursor (figure below).

[image]

This issue can be addressed by commenting the last statement of `::SetWindowPos(...)`. But I am wondering what the real cause is and whether it is OK to remove this statement, or any better fix.

Comment: Setting the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` styles might fix it. But fundamentally, why are you using a scrollbar control instead of just drawing a gripper?

Comment: See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36872343/4603670) for drawing a gripper

Comment: @JonathanPotter, that works, thank you!